# How to send Properties details in EventHub message using python?

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I am referring to this article "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send" related to sending messages to EventHub using Python.

A Message has the following components: offset, body, systemProperties, properties. 
**offset** is auto-generated but we can provide the other.

For my project - apart from message body I also need to send `"Properties"` which is not part of Body, How to do that? I checked the class `EventData(object)`: and looks like application_properties can be used to do this but i'm not sure how to implement this.

Is application_properties right analogy to obtain "Properties" in message?

Could you please add more details to the article with example displaying how to use the python EventData class for sending detailed information apart from message body like Properties and SystemProperties. **As of now Properties is being sent as empty list.**

Sample message format that i need to send to EventHub using Python:

```
Sender.send(EventData('{"**offset**":"2415248","**body**":"TESTone:100, 
Temperature:553.0","**systemProperties**":[{"key":{"string":"x-opt- 
sequence-number"},"value":{"string":"23512"}},{"key":{"string":"x-opt- 
offset"},"value":{"string":"2415248"}},{"key":{"string":"x-opt- 
enqueued-time"},"value":{"string":"Fri Feb 22 02:14:23 UTC 
2019"}}],"**properties**":[]}'))
```

And I want to send this dict values in **properties**: `{"key":{"string":"Type"},"value":{"string":"iPhone"}}`

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question elsewhere as the solution provided by PraveenS does not actually solve the problem. The correct answer which I received is below, sharing to help others:

The solution is to assign the properties you want to be sent with the message to EventData.properties, applying that to the above code would look like this:

```
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset, Sender, EventData
from uamqp import Message

ADDRESS = "amqps://<>.windows.net/<>"
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "<>"

client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=True, username=USER, password=KEY)
Sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")
client.run()

event = EventData(body="TESTTWO:100, Temperature:-127.0")
### THIS IS WHERE THE CHANGE IS ###
event.properties = {"Type": "iPhone"}
Sender.send(event)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution to this, yes we can use "application_properties" to send "properties" of message.
This is my sample code that worked:

```
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset, Sender, EventData
from uamqp import Message

ADDRESS = "amqps://<>.windows.net/<>"
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "<>"

client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=True, username=USER, password=KEY)
Sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")
client.run()

event = EventData(body="TESTTWO:100, Temperature:-127.0")
event.application_properties = {"Type": "iPhone"}
Sender.send(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also find useful the following way, which basically do the same:

```
props = {"Type": "iPhone"} # properties you want to send

columns = ['body', 'properties']
values = [(write_binneddata, props)] # You can also send multiple messages adding tuples to the list
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, columns)

conn_string = f"Endpoint=sb://{event_hub_namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={shared_acc_keyname};SharedAccessKey={shared_acc_key};EntityPath={event_hub_name}"
conf = { 'eventhubs.connectionString' : conn_string }

ds = (
  df
  .write 
  .format("eventhubs") 
  .options(**conf) 
  .option("checkpointLocation", f"{checkpoint_path}")
  .save()
)
```

PS: it needs [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark) library installed.