# Send jsonfiles to EventHub using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, azure-eventhub, sendfile

I need to send jsonfiles from my folder to azure-EventHub using Python

```
import json
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Sender, EventData


# Address can be in either of these formats:
# "amqps://<URL-encoded-SAS-policy>:<URL-encoded-SAS-key>@<mynamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub"
# "amqps://<mynamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub"
# SAS policy and key are not required if they are encoded in the URL
ADDRESS = "amqps://xxxxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/import"

# SAS policy and key are not required if they are encoded in the URL
USER = "xxx"
KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Create an Event Hubs client
client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)

# Add a sender to the client
sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")

# Run the Event Hub client
client.run()

# Send jsonfile one by one to the event hub from below folder
sender.send(EventData("C:/Users/shef123/Desktop/"))
```

My code didn't work,because i just started learning python. Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Did not work, can you explain? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Jsonfile sent successfully to EventHub. But issue is when i verify in Application its errored not success. Error message as "Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $". However when i try to send the same json file using Java there is no error in Application,so its not issue with JSON file or format. My question is using Java i can able to send json files successfully, why i am not able to send through Python. Am i missing any thing?

Comment: when you mean send jsonfile, you mean send a file or json string in the send method? and also what's the Application you see the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the with the way you are trying to send the data to event hub.You can't directly call this function and pass the folder for processing the file like you are doing below:

```
sender.send(EventData("C:/Users/shef123/Desktop/"))
```

You can check this link to read json files:

https://www.simplifiedpython.net/python-read-json-file/

you can read through JSON file from folder and one by one you can send it using the similar code.

You can find the code related to Send Data in beloe repo:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/examples/send_async.py

Check below link for reference too:

[How to send Properties details in EventHub message using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819998/how-to-send-properties-details-in-eventhub-message-using-python/54859156)

Comment: Wouldn't that just send the directory name as the event?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is that `EventData` object only takes **string or bytes**.
The Python SDK won't read the file for you and would only take that file path as a raw data string and send the string to the Event Hub.

So what you need to do is to open the file and load the contents into bytes array and then pass the bytes to `EventData` constructor -- `EventData(body=loaded_bytes)`.
Please note that there is a quota limitation of the event size based on the [tier you choose(basic/standard)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas).

---

It is worth noting that azure-eventhub v5 has been GAed in 2020 Jan.

It's available on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/

Please follow the [migration guide from v1 to v5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/migration_guide.md) to migrate your program.

There is also a sample folder [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples) for you to start with.